# Laravel - What is difference between reserved_at and available_at on Jobs table?

Tags: laravel, queue, background-process

I already try to find out in Google and Laravel Documentation. But hard to find what difference between

```
reserved_at
available_at
```

> Can anyone explain what the meaning of that column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`available_at` is when the job can be processed (delay). This field is set at creation at current time by default.

`reserved_at` is set if a worker has reserved the job so it doesn't overlap with other workers. Basically, so the job doesn't run twice in a parallel fashion by two different workers(process).This field is null at creation.

If you want to deep dive a bit, here is the [DatabaseQueue.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7212b1e9620c36bf806e444f6931cf5f379c68ff/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php#L170) that uses the fields.